# Logarithmic questions, on scaling and geometric mean

Tags: logarithms

I'm understanding logarithmic scales and have questions.  The axis coordinate for a number $x$ on the scale is $log_{10}(x) = y$.  This can then be used to create the tick marks where $x$ is the tick mark and $y$ is the coordinate on the scale as follows:

$T = \{(x,y) | (x = 10^p*l) \land (1 < l \le 9) \land l,p \in \mathbb{N} \land (y = log_{10}(x)) \}$

Something that mislead me, is that the tick marks are labeled by $b^p$ and not $p$ as I would have expected.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Does the description of coordinates and tick marks, $T$, look correct?
2. This [page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBhEi4L91Sg) and the following image explains that if the distance $p$ between two coordinates $a = (x_0, y_0), b = (x_1, y_1)$ is $d = y_1 - y_0$ and the factor between the tick marks $f = x_1 - x_0$, then $nf = nd$ and $\frac f n = \frac d n$.  What is happening here algebraically and in relation to logarithm?
3. This [page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8jR-_Om4myk) discusses how the geometric mean $\sqrt(a*b)$ is used to find the value between two tick marks.  It's my understanding it's used because the scale is logarithmic and a standard mean cannot be used.  Does anyone know the details on why the geometric mean can be use?

[image: Quest 1]

[image: Quest 2]

Comment: A normal scale is additive: each new tick mark adds to your total. A logarithmic scale is multiplicative: each new tick mark multiplies by the given base. The geometric mean is the "multiplicative halfway point" between two numbers, whereas on a normal scale, you use the usual arithmetic mean to get the "additive halfway point".

Comment: I think I understand the tick mark multiplication as posted earlier in the set theoretic form.  Where I'm confused is why  $log(2) - log(1) = log(4) - log(2)$.  Is this an identity?  $log_b(\frac 2 1) = log_b(\frac 4 2)$ apply $b^x$ on both sides is $\frac 2 1 = \frac 4 2 = 2$.  I think thats it, but I still am confused why.